# Why do I have to use the "exe" extension to launch a program in the command window?

Tags: windows-xp, command-line

I can no longer launch programs just by typing the program name in a command window.  For instance, typing "notepad" and then enter gives me "bad command or filename".  If I recall correctly Windows XP would automatically pick up the executable.  If I type "notepad.exe" and hit enter, then notepad starts as expected.  Did something change on my system, or did I just remember wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

did your PATHEXT environment variable get overwritten?

Comment: certainly looks like the "groovy" programming language is the only extension in there.

Comment: Yup.  that was it.  For some reason the groovy installation overwrote my PATHEXT.  I corrected the problem and everything works as it should.  Thanks!

Comment: Might want to contact Groovy and check if they have a bug. They shouldn't be changing PATHEXT, they should be using assoc.exe and filetypes.

Answer (score 0):

For your help the initial value of PATHEXT is: `.COM;.EXE;.BAT;.CMD;.VBS;.VBE;.JS;.JSE;.WSF;.WSH;.MSC` .